# How to amend jquery script to push the content down?

Tags: jquery, notifications

I am using jquery notifications, but the main problem is that it adds the notification on top of the content. I would like to push the content down. Any suggestions how to do this?

I call the script with this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
       showNotification({
            type : "success",
            message: "This is a sample success notification"
       }); 
    });
</script>
```

JQUERY:

```
/**
 * Javascript functions to show top nitification
 * Error/Success/Info/Warning messages
 * Developed By: Ravi Tamada
 * url: http://androidhive.info
 * © androidhive.info
 * 
 * Created On: 10/4/2011
 * version 1.0
 * 
 * Usage: call this function with params 
 showNotification(params);
 **/

function showNotification(params){
    // options array
    var options = { 
        'showAfter': 0, // number of sec to wait after page loads
        'duration': 0, // display duration
        'autoClose' : false, // flag to autoClose notification message
        'type' : 'success', // type of info message error/success/info/warning
        'message': '', // message to dispaly
        'link_notification' : '', // link flag to show extra description
        'description' : '' // link to desciption to display on clicking link message
    }; 
    // Extending array from params
    $.extend(true, options, params);

    var msgclass = 'succ_bg'; // default success message will shown
    if(options['type'] == 'error'){
        msgclass = 'error_bg'; // over write the message to error message
    } else if(options['type'] == 'information'){
        msgclass = 'info_bg'; // over write the message to information message
    } else if(options['type'] == 'warning'){
        msgclass = 'warn_bg'; // over write the message to warning message
    } 

    // Parent Div container
    var container = '<div id="info_message" class="'+msgclass+'"><div class="center_auto"><div class="info_message_text message_area">';
    container += options['message'];
    container += '</div><div class="info_close_btn button_area" onclick="return closeNotification()"></div><div class="clearboth"></div>';
    container += '</div><div class="info_more_descrption"></div></div>';

    $notification = $(container);

    // Appeding notification to Body
    $('body').append($notification);

    var divHeight = $('div#info_message').height();
    // see CSS top to minus of div height
    $('div#info_message').css({
        top : '-'+divHeight+'px'
    });

    // showing notification message, default it will be hidden
    $('div#info_message').show();

    // Slide Down notification message after startAfter seconds
    slideDownNotification(options['showAfter'], options['autoClose'],options['duration']);

    $('.link_notification').live('click', function(){
        $('.info_more_descrption').html(options['description']).slideDown('fast');
    });

}
// function to close notification message
// slideUp the message
function closeNotification(duration){
    var divHeight = $('div#info_message').height();
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('div#info_message').animate({
            top: '-'+divHeight
        }); 
        // removing the notification from body
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('div#info_message').remove();
        },200);
    }, parseInt(duration * 1000));   



}

// sliding down the notification
function slideDownNotification(startAfter, autoClose, duration){    
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('div#info_message').animate({
            top: 0
        }); 
        if(autoClose){
            setTimeout(function(){
                closeNotification(duration);
            }, duration);
        }
    }, parseInt(startAfter * 1000));    
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the css that you're using to style the added notification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your HTML file add a div where you want notification to appear like this:

```
<body>
    <div id="notificationDiv">
        This is the DIV, where you want notification to appear.
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        This is content of the page.
    </div>
</body>
```

Then just change the line in your JQUERY file:

```
// Appeding notification to Body
$('body').append($notification);
```

to this:

```
// Appeding notification to Body
$('#notificationDiv').html($notification);
```

You can check this out [there](http://jsfiddle.net/bZ737/3/).

To push the content down, in your jquery_notification.css file change this:

```
#info_message{
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 51px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 50000;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

... to this (delete both position properties):

```
#info_message{
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 51px;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 50000;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: I think I did everything what you said: added an extra div on top, added a line in the .js file $('#notificationDiv').html($notification);

Comment: but still I have the same result. You can check it on reprezentacija.lt

Comment: Thanks once again, it helped.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to insert notification container before content. You can then set initial height to 0, and animate height. The content will move down as the notification container will expand.

Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/yJYeb/1/

Comment: I cant get it how you do this and how I can apply it to my version. I even copied your version of javascript and still no good. It seems like your version is working even if I delete the "container". You can find my working sample at reprezentacija.lt. If you will have any other suggestions, I will really appreciate if you can share.

Comment: Try to remove `position:fixed` rule from `#info_message` in `jquery.notification.css`, then replace `$('div#info_message').css({ top : '-'+divHeight+'px' });` with `$('div#info_message').css({ height: '0px' });`, and finally change `$('div#info_message').animate({ top: 0 });` to `$('div#info_message').animate({ height: 51 });` in `jquery.notification.js`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, not a total solution... The problem is that the CSS is doubtless responsible for making the notification appear at the top of the page. In the Notification js, you will find the line

```
$('body').append($notification);
```

If you change that to

```
$('body').prepend($notification);
```

the notification will appear at the top, as long as you also ensure your css has:

```
#info_message {
   position:relative;
}
```

If there's a `position: absolute`, then your notification will float over the other text.

There will probably still be a bit of a jump of your content when the notification appears and disappears, but the rest of the animation should be ok. You probably need to mix expanding / contracting the height with the moving of the position to get a smooth transition, or use another library.

Comment: You can find a working sample at reprezentacija.lt. If you will have any other suggestions, I will really appreciate if you will share.